# run multiple lines of code based on ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to run multiple lines of code based on the results of an `if` or `ifelse` statement. The test expression will test the values of a column in a dataframe. Here is my problem:

`if` statements allow multiple statements to be executed only when the test expression is not a vector:

```
 if (test_expression) {
       statement1
       statement2
       statement3
    }
```

`ifelse` statements allow one statement to be executed when the test expression is a vector:

```
ifelse(test_expression, statement1, statement2)
```

However, what if you want to run an `if` statement on a vector and then run a whole section of code based on the results? In this example, the lines of code I want to run will make a plot. But in reality, I want to go much further than this (send the generated plot as an email attachment).

Example Data:

```
datetime <- c("12/6/2016 8:00","12/6/2016 8:00","12/6/2016 8:00","12/6/2016 8:00","12/6/2016 8:00","12/6/2016 8:00","12/6/2016 8:00","12/6/2016 8:00","12/6/2016 8:00","12/6/2016 8:00","12/6/2016 10:00","12/6/2016 10:00","12/6/2016 10:00","12/6/2016 10:00","12/6/2016 10:00","12/6/2016 10:00","12/6/2016 10:00","12/6/2016 10:00","12/6/201610:00","12/6/2016 10:00","12/6/2016 10:00","12/6/2016 10:00","12/6/2016 10:00","12/6/2016 10:00","12/6/2016 10:00","12/6/2016 12:00","12/6/2016 12:00","12/6/201612:00","12/6/2016 12:00","12/6/2016 12:00","12/6/2016 12:00","12/6/2016 12:00","12/6/2016 12:00","12/6/2016 12:00","12/6/2016 12:00","12/6/2016 12:00","12/6/201612:00","12/6/2016 12:00","12/6/2016 12:00","12/6/2016 12:00")

c <- c(2.41,1.68,2.29,2.09,3.47,2.28,2.56,2.52,2.27,1.74,2.03,2.14,2.77,2.34,1.78,2.53,2.68,2.27,1.83,1.69,1.83,2.3,2.07,1.91,2.16,3.11,2.38,2.63,2.47,2,2.35,2.11,2.03,3.2,2.17,2.58,2.64,2.23,2.12,2.17)

elev <- c(239.5312,242.8121,246.257,249.5378,252.6874,255.7714,259.2819,262.3331,265.8436,266.8278,222.6283,226.3685,229.7806,232.9302,236.211,239.5247,242.8055,245.9223,249.3344,252.7465,256.0601,259.1441,262.5234,265.9026,266.7885,222.6513,226.3915,229.8692,232.9531,236.2012,239.6133,242.8613,246.2406,249.4558,252.7694,256.0175,259.3639,262.6448,265.86,266.8442)

mydf <- data.frame(datetime,c,elev)

mydf$datetime <- strptime(mydf$datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

current.time <- "2016-12-06 12:00:00"

current.time <- paste(format(current.time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H"), ":00:00", sep = "")

current.date <- "2016-12-06" 

mydf2 <- subset(mydf, datetime == current.time)
mydf2 <- mydf2[order(-mydf2$elev),]
```

Example `if` statement:

```
if(mydf2$c > 2){
  filename<- paste("//C:/Alert_Profile_",current.date, ".pdf", sep="")
  pdf(filename, width=7, height=12)
  plot(0,type="n", ylim = c(216,285), xlim= c(0,35),ylab="Elevation (ft ASL)", xlab=expression('A ('*degree*'C)'))
  lines(mydf2$c, mydf2$elev, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ylim = c(216,285), xlim= c(0,35), col="mediumpurple1")
  points(mydf2$c, mydf2$elev, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ylim = c(216,285), xlim= c(0,35), pch=21, col="black", bg= "mediumpurple1")
  dev.off()     
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute a block of code if one of the value of a vector satisfy a condition, there's `any` which will return true if any value is TRUE.

Your if statement become: `if (any(mydf2$c > 2))`

---

Previous answer which may be of use also:

I would set your if condition as a logical vector:

```
lv <- mydf2$c > 2
```

Then call your block on subsetted data:

```
  filename<- paste("//C:/Alert_Profile_",current.date, ".pdf", sep="")
  pdf(filename, width=7, height=12)
  plot(0,type="n", ylim = c(216,285), xlim= c(0,35),ylab="Elevation (ft ASL)", xlab=expression('A ('*degree*'C)'))
  lines(mydf2$c[lv], mydf2$elev[lv], xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ylim = c(216,285), xlim= c(0,35), col="mediumpurple1")
  points(mydf2$c[lv], mydf2$elev[lv], xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ylim = c(216,285), xlim= c(0,35), pch=21, col="black", bg= "mediumpurple1")
  dev.off()
```

Or I may have not understood what you're after, as your question doesn't provide an expected output it's hard to tell, your example code will run or not depending on the first value of `mydf2$c`and raise a warning about this:

```
> d
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> if (d > 3) { print("ok")} 
Warning message:
In if (d > 3) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Sorry, my expected output in this case is a plot of `mydf2`, only when one of `mydf2$c` values exceeds 2. So I don't want to limit the plot to all values in excess of 2, but rather plot all of them when 1 or more exceeds too. Likewise, if none exceeds 2, I do not want to make a plot.

Comment: Then just turn your `if(mydf2$c 2)` into `if (any(myfdf2$c >2))`

Comment: duhhhhhhhhh......... thanks so much! Could you edit your answer to include the above solution? It may be helpful for others.